# Show Modal for msg with discordjs bot

Tags: discord.js

I would like my discord bot (made in javascipt) to respond to a message that starts with '!!' by opening a dialog modal (therefore without receiving an interaction).

I haven't found any documentation on whether this is possible or not.

My Message object obviously does not contain a valid interaction field (msg.interaction is null) and it is impossible to use method *showModal()*.

How can I solve the problem without first creating a component button and then responding to the interaction with it?

This is my code (a sintetic example):

```js
const { Events } = require('discord.js');

module.exports = {
    name: Events.MessageCreate,
    async execute(msg) {

        // If is message to a Bot ignore it
        if(msg.author.bot)
            return;

        // If message not start whit !! ignore it
        if(!msg.content.startsWith('!!'))
            return false;

        // Create example Modal, create text field and add to modal as actionRow
        const modal = new ModalBuilder()
            .setCustomId(id)
            .setTitle('Example modal');
        const exampleField = new TextInputBuilder()
            .setCustomId('example field')
            .setLabel("example label")
            .setStyle(TextInputStyle.Short);
        const firstActionRow = new ActionRowBuilder().addComponents(exampleField);
        modal.addComponents(firstActionRow);

        // send Modal whit msg is my problem !!!!!!
            // showModal metode not exist for Message 
            msg.showModal(modal);
            
            // interaction field is null
            msg.interaction.showModal(modal)
    }
};
```

Thanks for your help